# How can i create a django environment with cmd? It's working perfectly in anaconda shell, not in cmd

Tags: python, anaconda

This is the error message:

> C:\Windows\system32>conda create --name leo django Collecting package
>   metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
>   Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by the following commands:

conda init cmd.exe

you can also change yours according to the terminal you are using, for example, if you wish to switch from conda terminal to linux terminal, you can use the following command:

conda init bash

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add conda to the os path